# Creating a Sitecore User with read only access to all the Sitecore items

Tags: sitecore-client

How can I create a Sitecore user with read only access to all the sitecore items.

I came across below sitecore link, but this required to assign the permissions by item wise. which takes time. so want to know is there a better way to do permissions instead of item and user level.
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/assign-access-rights-to-a-security-account.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Role for this with read only access and grant read access to all the top level nodes in Content Tree and apply the same permission to Descendants.

[image]

Once the role is created, Assign the users to this role.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Applying the permissions to Descendants seems to be not working. I tried that, sub items are editable even after applying the permissions to Descendants.
i am using sitecore 9.0.2, is there any bug in that version.

Comment: You may inherit the write access, so you can deny inheritance for descendants on the parent item where you have define the security. In access viewer, if you see the write access enabled, by clicking on it you can see where it comes from. Otherwise it can be just cache.